# Setting up buildpath in Eclipse for this GitHub repo?

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

I am having some difficulties trying to clone this repository from GitHub
https://github.com/eugener/oxbow

However, my build path is all jacked up and I don't quite know which folder(s) are supposed to be the "source" folders. Can someone who is savvy with GitHub projects in Eclipse please tell me what my .project and .classpath files are supposed to look like?

I'm just trying to pull it down, make a tweak or two, and package the darned thing in a JAR file for my use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Eclipse project is in a sub-folder of that repo, `/swingbits`. If you import that existing project into your Eclipse workspace it will automatically detect the `.project` and `.classpath` files that are there. If you have Eclipse m2e installed, it will also detect that this is a Maven project and treat it appropriately.

Comment: Wow that was simple! Thank you.